Android app crashing with error: [PropertyFetcher]: TimeoutException getting properties for device
I am trying to run a react native based application in debugging mode. But it is throwing TimeoutException.
Development Environment:
using Android OS XOS v12.0.0 (OS12.0-S-P156-221214)
java --version 
openjdk 11.0.22 2024-01-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.22+7-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu222.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.22+7-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu222.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)

adb --version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 34.0.1-9680074

react-native: 0.72.4

Execution log:
> Task :app:installDebug
[PropertyFetcher]: TimeoutException getting properties for device 0965731355092050
java.lang.Throwable: TimeoutException getting properties for device 0965731355092050
 at com.android.ddmlib.PropertyFetcher.handleException(PropertyFetcher.java:248)
 at com.android.ddmlib.PropertyFetcher$1.run(PropertyFetcher.java:211)
Caused by: com.android.ddmlib.TimeoutException
 at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.read(AdbHelper.java:1201)
 at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.readAdbResponse(AdbHelper.java:353)
 at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:650)
 at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:511)
 at com.android.ddmlib.internal.DeviceImpl.executeShellCommand(DeviceImpl.java:719)
 at com.android.ddmlib.PropertyFetcher$1.run(PropertyFetcher.java:207)

[PropertyFetcher]: TimeoutException getting properties for device 0965731355092050
java.lang.Throwable: TimeoutException getting properties for device 0965731355092050
 at com.android.ddmlib.PropertyFetcher.handleException(PropertyFetcher.java:248)
 at com.android.ddmlib.PropertyFetcher$1.run(PropertyFetcher.java:211)
Caused by: com.android.ddmlib.TimeoutException
 at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.read(AdbHelper.java:1201)
 at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.readAdbResponse(AdbHelper.java:353)
 at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:650)
 at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:511)
 at com.android.ddmlib.internal.DeviceImpl.executeShellCommand(DeviceImpl.java:719)
 at com.android.ddmlib.PropertyFetcher$1.run(PropertyFetcher.java:207)

Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'Pixel_XL_API_31(AVD) - 12' for :app:debug
[PropertyFetcher]: TimeoutException getting properties for device 0965731355092050
java.lang.Throwable: TimeoutException getting properties for device 0965731355092050
 at com.android.ddmlib.PropertyFetcher.handleException(PropertyFetcher.java:248)
 at com.android.ddmlib.PropertyFetcher$1.run(PropertyFetcher.java:211)
Caused by: com.android.ddmlib.TimeoutException
 at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.read(AdbHelper.java:1201)
 at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.readAdbResponse(AdbHelper.java:353)
 at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:650)
 at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:511)
 at com.android.ddmlib.internal.DeviceImpl.executeShellCommand(DeviceImpl.java:719)
 at com.android.ddmlib.PropertyFetcher$1.run(PropertyFetcher.java:207)

Skipping device '0965731355092050' for ':app:debug': Unknown API Level

In Emulator every thing is working fine. With some other devices it is also working fine. Not able to even install the app.
I tried:

Disabling adb authorization timeout
Tried revoking USB debugging authorization and then running it.

